# The meaning of induced sheaf $\mathscr F_y$ in Hartshorne's Corollary III.9.4

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I do not quite understand Corollary III.9.4 on page 255 of Hartshorne's Algebraic geometry. 
I quote the corollary here before I post my questions:

Let $f:\, X \to Y$ be a separated morphism of finite type of noetherian
schemes, and let $\mathscr F$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$. Assume $Y$ affine. For
any point $y \in Y$, let $X_y$ be the fibre over $y$, and let $\mathscr F_y$ be the induced sheaf. On the other hand, let $k(y)$ denote the constant sheaf $k(y)$ on the closed
subset $\{y\}^-$ of $Y$. Then for all $i \ge  0$ there are natural isomorphisms
$$H^i(X_y,\mathscr F_y) \cong  H^i(X,\mathscr F \otimes k(y)).$$

My first question is: what does the induced sheaf $\mathscr F_y$ mean here?  I think it is $j^*(\mathscr F)$, where $j$ is the natural inclusion $j:\, X_y \hookrightarrow X$ but I am not sure.

My second question (I do not know if it is appropriate to ask here. But please excuse me if it is not) is if someone could briefly (or in detail) to explain the proof of the corollary given in the book. It seems to me I can not follow the proof everywhere.

Thank you for everybody who can give me some help.

Comment: This will get closed because it's not research level math. You should ask it on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: That corollary is indeed very strange. I would suggest to skip it and go on, you won't need it to continue reading the book.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_y$ is indeed $j^*(\mathcal{F})$.  This corollary just follows from the identification $j_*j^*\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}\otimes k(y)$ and the fact that $j$ is an affine morphism, so $j_*$ is acyclic.